# How to convert TChar[] array to std::string in VC++. Help on syntax

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi I have an array of type TCHAR arr[256]. I want to convert this TChar array to a std::string, so that I will able use the functions in the string class.

Can anyone kindly let me know how to do this TCHAR[] to string conversion in VC++.

**Also what is the syntax to do this:**

```
If TCHAR arr[256] is my array. 
std::string str is my straing obj
```

.
Will the foll syntax work fine: 
str = arr;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I do it like this:

```
TCHAR arr[256];
std::wstring arr_w( arr );
std::string arr_s( arr_w.begin(), arr_w.end() );
```

result is in arr_s

Dont expect any chars outside standart ASCII to be converted though

Comment: I am getting the error :C2064:    "TERM DOES NOT EVALUATE TO A FUNCTION TAKING 1 ARGUMENT" FOR "std::wstring arr_w( arr ); "

Comment: sIMILIARLY TERM DOES NOT EVALUATE TO A FUNCTION TAKING 1 ARGUMENT" FOR statement "std::string arr_s( arr_w.begin(), arr_w.end() ); ".       It is considering arr_s & arr_w to be functions.

Comment: @engineer - Including `<string>` header?

Comment: Does that compile when TCHAR = CHAR?